# How to use submit button to search the record in a table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-filter, angularjs-forms

Here is my index.html page
  ------index.html-------

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <head>
             <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6"
     src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>   
             <script src="script.js"></script>
         </head>
         <body>

     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl"> <input type="text"
     name="search1" >

     <input type="submit" ng-model="search1"   value="search"
     ng-click="checkAll"> <table border="1"  ng-init="ageToShow=(people|
     underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">


     <tr name="search1" > <th>Id</th> <th>Name</th> <th ng-show="ageToShow"
    ng-if="!ageToShow">Age</th> </tr> <tr ng-repeat="person in
     people|filter: search" ng-show="person.age>20" >
     <td><span>{{person.id}}</span> </td> <td><span>{{person.name}}</span>
     </td> <td ng-show="!ageToShow"><span>{{person.age}}</span> </td> </tr>
     </table>

     </div> </body> </html>
```

---

### What i need is to  use submit button to  search  the record .... And here is my  script.js file...

```
--------script.js--------
     // Code goes here



     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {

       $scope.people = ([{
         id: 1,
         name: "Peter",
         age: 22   }, {
         id: 2,
         name: "David",
        age: 12   }, {
         id: 3,
         name: "Anil",
         age: 32   }, {
         id: 4,
         name: "Chean",
         age: 22   }, {
         id: 5,
         name: "Niladri",
         age: 18   }
         ]);





        $scope.people3 = $scope.people;

         $scope.$watch('search1', function(val)
         { 
            $scope.people = $filter('filter')($scope.people3, val);
         });



          }); myApp.filter('underTwenty', function() {

       return function(values, limit) {
         var returnValue = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function(val, ind) {
           if (val.age < limit)

            returnValue.push(val);
             });   return returnValue;   }; });
```

And here goes my coding in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: There is no code in plunker....

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BhkbPXqcApA3BOm30qdG?p=preview

Comment: sorry  i have updated  it without saving ........

Comment: Instead of using submit, I would simply use different `ng-model` for search textbox and on click of button I'd bind it to `search` variable like `ng-click= search=dummySearch`

Comment: If i give ng-model into  textbox   i.e, <input type="text" ng-model="xyz"> it directly  binds the records in the table but what i need is to use the submit button to  search the the records or bind the particular record which i type in the textbox........

Comment: @anilchean check this plunkr I think your `$watch ` was making problem. take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/o9SOH9IT7mLlHo0mafC3?p=preview and let me know if you required anything

Comment: Thank u @ pankajparkar it works now this is wat  i was searching till now

Comment: @anilchean  should i add answer?

Comment: @anilchean I've added an answer..Kindly look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for filtering if you are planning to do submit the form, then I'll suggest you to don't prefer form submit.

Form getting the same requirement done I'd create one dummy field for search text-box & then I'd assign that would to `search` model which we using for filter on click of search `ng-click="search = search1"`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="search1" ng-model="search1"/>
<input type="button" value="search" ng-click="search = search1">
<table border="1" ng-init="ageToShow=(people| underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">
  <tr name="search1">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th ng-show="ageToShow" ng-if="!ageToShow">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people|filter: search" ng-show="person.age>20">
    <td><span>{{person.id}}</span> 
    </td>
    <td><span>{{person.name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td ng-show="!ageToShow"><span>{{person.age}}</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

& Do remove the watch from `search1` variable. So the filtering will not occur on change of `search1`

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o9SOH9IT7mLlHo0mafC3?p=preview)